# Building CMake with NASM format defined in sub-directory

Tags: assembly, cmake, nasm

I'm trying to write an architecture dependent application using NASM as my assembler and CMake as my build system. The project structure is roughly as follows:

```
CMakeLists.txt
 |_ include/
 |_ base/    
     |_ CMakeLists.txt
     |_ ...
     |_ arch/
         |_ aarch64
         |   |_ CMakeLists.txt
         |   |_ ...
         |_ i386
         |   |_ CMakeLists.txt
         |   |_ ...
         |_ riscv32
             |_ CMakeLists.txt
             |_ ...
```

`./CMakeLists.txt`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.25)
set(CFG_ARCH "riscv32")
set(CFG_VERSION "1.0")

include_directories(BEFORE SYSTEM ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/)
project(runner C ASM_NASM)
add_subdirectory(base)
```

`./base/CMakeLists.txt`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.25)
set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 11)
add_executable(base main.c)
add_subdirectory(arch/${CFG_ARCH}/)
target_compile_options(base PUBLIC -ffreestanding)
target_link_options(base PUBLIC -ffreestanding -nostdlib -Wl,--build-id=none -z noexecstack)
target_link_libraries(base PUBLIC
    arch_${CFG_ARCH}
)
```

e.g. `./base/arch/riscv32/CMakeLists.txt`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.25)

set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Generic CACHE INTERNAL "")
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "-target riscv32-none-elf" CACHE INTERNAL "")
set(CMAKE_ASM_NASM_OBJECT_FORMAT elf32 CACHE INTERNAL "" FORCE)

add_library(arch_riscv32 STATIC
    ...
)
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "-T ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/linker.ld" CACHE INTERNAL "")
```

My problem is that in order to use NASM with CMake, I need to call `project(... ASM_NASM)` at top level, but my target architecture doesn't get defined until after I've added the `base/arch/...` sub-directory, at which point I'm no longer able to modify the `CMAKE_ASM_NASM_OBJECT_FORMAT` property.
In every case, CMake will default to my system's current output format (`elf64`) and ignore any change I throw at it since it's appended to the end of the final command.

Is it possible to retain this kind of project structure and set the NASM object format globally from a sub-directory?

Comment: Setting variable `CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME` implies **cross-compiling**. CMake should be aware of that when it detects a compiler in the **first** `project()` call. Such setting is better to be performed in the **toolchain file**, which path are specified in the `CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE` variable: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-toolchains.7.html#cross-compiling-toolchain. You may set this variable in the `CMakeLists.txt` before the first `project()` call. Appending `-target` options to `CMAKE_C_FLAGS` and setting `CMAKE_ASM_NASM_OBJECT_FORMAT` should also be performed in the toolchain.

Comment: This works, but doesn't solve the actual issue since I can't select the toolchain file from a subdirectory.

Comment: Why do you think that toolchain selection should be deferred until the subdirectory? That toolchain affects not only files in the subdirectory, but also C files created in the upper directories. So the toolchain should be set when you compile those files in the `CMakeLists.txt`. In your toolchain file you may select different compilers according to some options. E.g. by using `include(${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/base/arch/${CFG_ARCH}/toolchain.cmake)` (assuming you have the main toolchain file in the top-level directory of your project).

Comment: Because I thought it'd be a good idea to abstract the format/target to an implementation in a subdirectory which takes care of everything. In hindsight, this isn't as practical as you have described it, thanks.